# Count the number of specfic patterns in a column

Tags: awk

Given the file below, I would like to calculate the frequency of the occurrence of each pattern that are not identical for each column, that is:

```
A/A C/G C/G
A/T C/C G/G
A/A C/G C/C
A/T C/G C/G
T/T C/G C/G
```

Output:

```
A/T = 2/5
C/G = 4/5
C/G = 3/5
```

I have tried some code in AWK but does not seem to work. I'd appreciate it some help, thanks!

Edit:

I recreated my file as follow:

```
A A C G C G
A T C C G G
A A C G C C
A T C G C G
T T C G C G

awk '$1 != $2 {n++}; END {print n}' file
```

This gives me the number of occurrence that I want for first two columns. I want now to loop over the columns, and check if every two columns are equal, that is 1 with 2, 3 with 4, etc.

How could I achieve looping over odd numbered columns only?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: So where *is* that code, and what precisely does *"does not seem to work"* mean?

Comment: You now have 2 separate questions, thanks to your edit. Which one should we answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('file.txt', 'r') as raw_data:
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in raw_data.readlines()]
a = [record[0] for record in data]
b = [record[1] for record in data]
c = [record[2] for record in data]

print Counter(a)
print Counter(b)
print Counter(c)
```

It prints the data as a dictionary, but you can handle it from now on, right ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the lines in memory at all, you can also use the csv lib to do the parsing:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
with open('file.txt', 'r') as raw_data:
    cn_a, cn_b, cn_c = Counter(),Counter(), Counter()
    for a ,b, c in csv.reader(raw_data,delimiter=" "):
        cn_a[a] += 1
        cn_b[b] += 1
        cn_c[c] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help. Yet, maybe, there are better ways to do it:

```
text = """A/A C/G C/G
A/T C/C G/G
A/A C/G C/C
A/T C/G C/G
T/T C/G C/G"""

first_column = list()
second_column = list()
third_column = list()

for row in text.strip().split('\n'):
    columns = row.split()
    first_column.append(columns[0])
    second_column.append(columns[1])
    third_column.append(columns[2])

first_column_ocurrences = dict((i, "{}/{}".format(first_column.count(i), len(first_column))) for i in first_column)
second_column_ocurrences = dict((i, "{}/{}".format(second_column.count(i), len(second_column))) for i in second_column)
third_column_ocurrences = dict((i, "{}/{}".format(third_column.count(i), len(third_column))) for i in third_column)

print "First column:"
print "-------------"
for k,v in first_column_ocurrences.items():
    print "{} = {}".format(k,v)

print "\nSecond column:"
print "-------------"

for k,v in second_column_ocurrences.items():
    print "{} = {}".format(k,v)

print "\nThird column:"
print "-------------"

for k,v in third_column_ocurrences.items():
    print "{} = {}".format(k,v)
```

Output:

```
First column:
-------------
A/T = 2/5
T/T = 1/5
A/A = 2/5

Second column:
-------------
C/C = 1/5
C/G = 4/5

Third column:
-------------
G/G = 1/5
C/C = 1/5
C/G = 3/5
```

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

works for any even number of columns.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) 
         if($i!=$(i+1)) 
             a["column "i": "$i"/"$(i+1)]++} 
  END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]"/"NR}' file

column 1: A/T 2/5
column 3: C/G 4/5
column 5: C/G 3/5
```